# what is the meaning of plt.legend without argument name?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to use `plt.legend` to make annotations on my plot, but I don't get the meaning of the '[11,12]' argument. It didn't say which argument it belongs to.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 11)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
l1, = ax1.plot(x, x*x, 'r')             #这里关键哦
l2, = ax2.plot(x, x*x, 'b')           # 注意

plt.legend([l1, l2], ['first', 'second'], loc = 'upper right')             #其中，loc表示位置的；

plt.show()
```

Can anybody explain which argument in `plt.legend` [11,12] belongs to?

Comment: I do not see any `[11, 12]` argument in `plt.legend()`. I see `[l1, l2]`, which is the list of plots to be labeled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be the following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly defining the elements in the legend

For full control of which artists have a legend entry, it is possible to pass an iterable of legend artists followed by an iterable of legend labels respectively:

legend((line1, line2, line3), ('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))

Comment: If you're going to copy the doc, maybe [link to it](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html?highlight=legend#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend)?